# Save file with variable text in file name in R

Tags: r

in R I'm trying to read in a file name where part of the file name references a string variable.  I'm having issues with the paste function.

Without the variable reference I was reading the file as follows:

```
adp <- readxl::read_xlsx('Data//2020-08-28 Hours.xlsx')
```

I also have the following variable:

```
pdate <- as.Date('2020-08-28')
```

I tried to incorporate the variable as follows, but something is wrong with my syntax:

```
adp <- readxl::read_xlsx(paste(''Data//'. pdate, 'Hours.xlsx'')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
readxl::read_xlsx(paste0('Data//', pdate, ' Hours.xlsx'))
```